# Consolidating CSS/JS with conflicts on separate pages

Tags: css, optimization, request

The answer to this may be "it depends," but it never hurts to ask.

Basically, I have several logical css/js files (`everything`, `index`, `user`).  I can't consolidate all of the CSS into a single file because some of the seperate pages share style rules and overwrite some components of them.  For example

```
/* everything.css */
body {
   /* lots of important rules here */
}

/* index.css */
body {
   background-color: blue;
}

/* user.css */
body {
   background-color: red;
}
```

As you can see, I can't consolidate all the CSS into a single file because of these conflicts.  This applies even moreso for the JavaScript.

My question is: is it better to consolidate per-page CSS/JS into a single file to reduce the number of requests, or does this outweigh the benefit of caching individual files from visiting other pages.

`everything.css` is fairly large, but once you visit either `index` or `user`, it will be **cached** so it doesn't have to be loaded again if you visit the other.  *On the other hand*, keeping it separate results in an **additional** request.

Is there a consensus on whether it's better to have one CSS/JS request per page vs. the benefit of caching when switching pages?

Is there another solution I've ignored?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it depends - if you don't have too many css and javascript files that you're linking to then you can actually see some performance benefit from having multiple files. Although each file will result in a separate request, those requests are done by most browsers in parallel and this can often result in a slight performance boost for the client (of course the server will take a bit more of a hit because of the extra request, but in reality this should be negligible).

If you're looking at 2 css files per page - 1 for your site-wide styles, and 1 for your page specific files I wouldn't worry about combining them into 1.  However if you have about 20 css files, then maybe you should be combining them.

Also, you should obviously minify your css files and enable gzip/deflate compression on your web server.

Comment: That sounds good .. I pretty much have the two files per-page (and a CDN that compresses).  I was thinking that the cache may not benefit so much since Yahoo says something like 40% of people visit with an empty cache, and the pages per visit on average is less than 2 (maybe my site just sucks).  For JS it's a little different since I have a bunch of external includes.  I may look into having one JS file-per page even if I don't with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript I would say, *always* concatenate and minify it into a single file. The only exception is where bandwidth matters (mobile). If you have conflicts, you probably didn't organize your JavaScript properly. There is a great introduction on how to use namespacing and modules in JavaScript in [Learning JavaScript design patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailnamespacing).

For CSS it depends. I always try and keep the core style framework together and then load customized styles as needed. Tools like [Less](http://lesscss.org/) can make this a lot easier.

Comment: I'm not sure that the JS necessarily has conflicts, but it's wasteful to load the relatively large `user.js` on the index page when it won't be used.  There may be some conflicts here and there because of class name similarities for styling, but I think those could be pretty easy to get around.

Answer (score 1):

In general you want only one CSS file per page and you may as well make it global across the site so that it can be cached.

The browser needs the CSS before it can start to render the page and the initial TCP connections will suffer from slow start and other connection overheads (although modern browsers will speculatively open TCP connections to try to overcome some of this)

Slow-start means that retrieving the CSS as two files is likely to be slower than retrieving it as one larger file plus it free's up a connection to start receiving other content.

I would really recommend reading John Rauser's [TCP and the Lower Bound of Web Performance](http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/44/TCP%20and%20the%20Lower%20Bound%20of%20Web%20Performance%20Presentation.pdf)